# StripInaccessible not removing fields

Tags: stripinaccessible

I am system administrator. I have removed edit access of contact fields Department, Assistant.

I am executing this code:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static SObjectAccessDecisionWrapper updateRecords(List<SObject> records) {
    try {
        System.debug('records**: ' + records);
        SObjectAccessDecision decision = Security.stripInaccessible(AccessType.UPDATABLE, records, true);
        System.debug('decision.getRecords()**: ' + decision.getRecords());
        update decision.getRecords();
        return new SObjectAccessDecisionWrapper(decision);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ApplicationException().auraHandled(e);
    }
}
```

These are the logs printing:

> records**: (Contact:{Department=dp1, AssistantName=pep,
> FirstName=pepeeaa, Phone=bs22, Id=0031n00002QwekhAAB})

> decision.getRecords()**: (Contact:{Department=dp1, AssistantName=pep,
> FirstName=pepeeaa, Phone=bs22, Id=0031n00002QwekhAAB})

`decision.getRemovedFields();` is empty. Why it is not removing the fields from the incoming records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System Administrator Profile comes with `Modify All Data    Checked` hardcoded in the profile.  This overrides the field level security settings:
["View All" and "Modify All" Permissions Overview](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.users_profiles_view_all_mod_all.htm&type=5)

If you want to validate the FLS and Security.stripInaccessible, then try using `System.runAs(User)`:
[Using the runAs Method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm)